# change div color if mouse out on div after 5sec not back mouseover then change color of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to change color of div
when mouse out of this div then not back 5sec on this div then change div background color
here is some code to make get last mouse out time from the div

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Effects - Animate demo</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <style>
    #effect { width: 240px; padding: 0.4em; position: relative; background: yellow; }
  </style>
  <script>
  var sec = 0;
        function pad ( val ) { return val > 9 ? val : "0" + val; }
        setInterval( function(){
            $("#effect").attr("name",pad(++sec%60));
        }, 1000);
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#effect").mouseout(function (){
            var time = $(this).attr("name");
            alert("at Mouse out:- "+time+" Second ");
        });
        });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="effect" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">ON Ready Status...
</div>
</body>
</html>
<script>
</script>
```

How can I change div color after 5 sec. of mouse out?

Comment: use `setTimeout()` instead

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/WLhpU/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    $("#test").on('mouseenter', function() {
        $("#test").css('background-color', 'red');
    });


    $("#test").on('mouseleave', function() {
            var timer=self.setInterval(function() {   
           $("#test").css('background-color', 'blue');
            window.clearInterval(timer);},5000);
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jsAgX/

Answer (score 1):

use following to run your code after 5 seconds

```
setTimeout(function() {
//your code
},5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
#effect.mouseout {
    background: red;
}
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#effect").hover(function () {
        var $this = $(this)
        clearTimeout($this.data('mouseouttimer'));
        $this.removeClass('mouseout');
    }, function () {
        var $this = $(this)
        var timer = setTimeout(function () {
            $this.addClass('mouseout');
        }, 2000);
        $this.data('mouseouttimer', timer);
    }).trigger('mouseleave');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/WLhpU/)